# Vastly different I-squared scores between metagen and metareg outputs

Tags: r, regression, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I've calculated a meta-analysis using the package *Meta* in r. The results of my analysis indicated an I-squared value of 82%:

```
   tau^2 = 0.5244 [0.3312; 2.7139]; tau = 0.7241 [0.5755; 1.6474];
   I^2 = 82.9% [72.5%; 89.3%]; H = 2.42 [1.91; 3.06]
```

To account for this heterogeneity, we are running a meta-regression via *metareg*. When doing so, however, our I-squared value in 20% lower:

```
tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.2033 (SE = 0.1655)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.4509
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 62.44%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   2.66
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            75.38%
```

In my previous meta-analyses through these packages, the I-squared values between the two models as above never differed, even with high r-squared values and significant Qm,e statistics.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be occurring?

My code is as follows:

```
Meta1 <- metagen(TE = LogOdds, seTE = SE, data = data, comb.random = T, method.tau = "DL")

Reg <- metareg(Meta1, method.tau = 'REML', IV1 + as.factor(IV2))
```

**Edit 1**: For anyone else who may be facing this challenge, make sure you check both within and between-subject variation changes. As it turns out, with this meta-regression, I am accounting for 75% of total heterogeneity.

The reason why I was still achieving high R-squared values without a change in my I-squared scores was that the regressions were only accounting for between-subject variation. Therefore there was a significant reduction in tau-squared, but not I-squared

Comment: DL is not REML?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I'm using REML as we have a relatively small dataset for meta purposes. When switching to DL for metareg, it causes I-squared to go even lower (58%). I do not understand why this is happening, as this I-squared value, like with my other models should match my metagen output (82%)

Comment: Different methods of estimating $\tau^2$ will give different values for $\tau^2$ and hence for $I^2$. Is that the cause of your problem?

Comment: I've posted what I believe to be the problem in my post. Thanks for the help!